# How to regenerate web.config file?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, web-config

I am making a asp.net mvc project. It works fine on localhost but after deploying it was causing many errors related to web.config file.
So i deleted that web.config file. Now i want my application to regenerate web.config file. How can i achieve that?
I know that there was a problem with web.config file because i replaced it with web.config file of another and it is working now but i don't want to take any risks so i would prefer file of this project only.

Comment: Are you not using source code control? Git? SVN? Mercurial? Using source code control is absolutely essential in software development.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have a few options here:

1. You can add a Web.config file at any time by right clicking your Web project, clicking add new item, and selecting "Web Configuration File." Then copy the contents of your known good Web.config into this new file through Visual Studio.

[image: Web Configuration File]

2. You can copy the Web.config that is deployed currently to your project through the file system. Place the Web.config in the Project folder:

[image: Project Folder]

Then, click on the "Show all files" button in solution explorer and include your new Web.config in the project by right clicking the file and selecting "Include in project."

[image: Include in Project]

3. If you don't have any copy of the Web.config, you can create a new Web project through visual studio, and copy that Web.config as described in #2. You will most likely have to update settings like the connection string and assembly bindings.

May I also suggest using source control in the future, if that is applicable to you and your project. There are tons of free options out there like VSO/Team Services and GitHub to name a couple.